# What are the output comment and hide comment in jsp?

Tags: jsp, comments

Hiii
Recently i came across these terms like output comment and hide comment in jsp.
Would like to know the differences between them.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Output Comment:**

A comment that is sent to the client in the viewable page source(it is appear in the output).

```
<!-- output comment -->
```

**Hidden Comment:**

A comments that documents the JSP page but is not sent to the client(it is not appear in output ).

```
<%-- hidden comment --%>
```